# C++ OPENGL checking positions of multiple objects against all other objects in list

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a pool table physics program in c++ with opengl that has a random number of balls that are all given random velocities at compile time and bounce around the table and off each other.

Although I am a little confused as to how I would check if any ball in the list is in the same place or colliding with the sides of each other.

How do I make up a loop to check each balls position against every other ball in the list?

Here is the code I have in my main:

```
#pragma once
// Math constants
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>  
#include <random>
#include<iterator>

// Std. Includes
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/matrix_operation.hpp>
#include "glm/ext.hpp"

// Other Libs
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

// project includes
#include "Application.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Body.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Force.h"
#include "RigidBody.h"
#include "Sphere.h"


// time
GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;

// main function
int main()
{
    // create application
    Application app = Application::Application();
    app.initRender();
    Application::camera.setCameraPosition(glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f));

    // create ground plane
    Mesh plane = Mesh::Mesh(Mesh::QUAD);
    plane.scale(glm::vec3(30.0f, 5.0f, 30.0f));
    Shader lambert = Shader("resources/shaders/physics.vert", "resources/shaders/physics.frag");
    plane.setShader(lambert);

//Create Sphere
    Mesh sphere = Mesh::Mesh("resources/models/sphere.obj");
    sphere.setShader(Shader("resources/shaders/solid.vert", "resources/shaders/solid_blue.frag"));

    Gravity g = Gravity(glm::vec3(0.0f, -9.8f, 0.0f));

    std::vector<Sphere>spheres;

    int rNum = rand() % 30 + 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < rNum; i++)
    {
        Sphere s;
        int pos_z = rand() % 20;
        int pos_x = rand() % 20;
        int vel_z = (rand() % 30) - 20;
        int vel_x = (rand() % 30) - 20;
        s.setMesh(sphere);
        s.getMesh().setShader(lambert);
        s.translate(glm::vec3(pos_x, 0.5f, pos_z));
        s.scale(glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        s.rotate((GLfloat)M_PI_2, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        s.setVel(glm::vec3(vel_x, 0.0f, vel_z));
        s.setCor(1.0f);
        s.addForce(&g);
        spheres.push_back(s);
    }

    glm::vec3 table(30.0f, 0.5f, 30.0f);

    // time
    GLfloat t = 0.0;
    GLfloat dt = 0.02;
    GLfloat currentTime = (GLfloat)glfwGetTime();
    GLfloat accumulator = 0.0;

// Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(app.getWindow()))
    {
        // Set frame time
        GLfloat newTime = (GLfloat)glfwGetTime();
        GLfloat frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
        currentTime = newTime;
        accumulator += frameTime;


        /*
        **  INTERACTION
        */
        // Manage interaction
        app.doMovement(dt);

        while (accumulator >= dt)
        {

            /*
            **  SIMULATION
            */

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++)
            {
                spheres[i].setAcc(spheres[i].applyForces(spheres[i].getPos(), spheres[i].getVel(), t, dt));
                spheres[i].setAngVel(spheres[i].getAngVel() + dt * spheres[i].getAngAcc());
                glm::mat3 angVelSkew = glm::matrixCross3(spheres[i].getAngVel());
                glm::mat3 R = glm::mat3(spheres[i].getRotate());
                R += dt * angVelSkew * R;
                R = glm::orthonormalize(R);
                spheres[i].setRotate(glm::mat4(R));
                spheres[i].setVel(spheres[i].getVel() + spheres[i].getAcc() * dt);
                spheres[i].translate(dt * spheres[i].getVel());



                if (spheres[i].getPos().y < table[1])
                {
                    spheres[i].setPos(1, table[1]);
                    spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3(spheres[i].getVel().x * spheres[i].getCor(), spheres[i].getVel().y * -spheres[i].getCor(), spheres[i].getVel().z * spheres[i].getCor()));
                }
                if (spheres[i].getPos().y > table[1])
                {
                    spheres[i].setPos(1, table[1]);
                }

                //length
                if (spheres[i].getPos().x > table[0])
                {

                    spheres[i].setPos(0, table[0]);
                    spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3(spheres[i].getVel().x * -spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f));
                }
                if (spheres[i].getPos().x < -table[0])
                {
                    spheres[i].setPos(0, -table[0]);
                    spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3(spheres[i].getVel().x * -spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f));

                }

                //width
                if (spheres[i].getPos().z < -table[2])
                {
                    spheres[i].setPos(2, -table[2]);
                    spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3((spheres[i].getVel().x * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * -spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f)));
                }
                if (spheres[i].getPos().z > table[2])
                {
                    spheres[i].setPos(2, table[2]);
                    spheres[i].setVel(glm::vec3((spheres[i].getVel().x * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().y * spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f, spheres[i].getVel().z * -spheres[i].getCor() / 1.5f)));
                }

            }

            accumulator -= dt;
            t += dt;

        }

        /*
        **  RENDER
        */
        // clear buffer
        app.clear();

        // draw groud plane
        app.draw(plane);

        for each (Sphere s in spheres)
        {
            app.draw(s.getMesh());
        }

        app.display();
    }

    app.terminate();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What kind of loop would I need to check the positions of each one against each other? (I still need to get it to check for sides colliding but if I can figure this out first I may be able to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 balls are colliding if its distance is closer than the sum of its radii.

Use 2 nested loops to verify if 2 balls from a list of *N* balls are colliding. The outer loop traverse all balls (`for i from 0 to N-1`) and the inner loop starts at the successor of the currently investigated ball (`for j from i+1 to N-1`).
The distance between 2 point can be get by [`glm::distance`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00279.html#gaa68de6c53e20dfb2dac2d20197562e3f).

e.g.

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++)
{
    for (size_t j = i+1; j < spheres.size(); j++)
    {
        float d = glm::distance(spheres[i].getPos(), spheres[j].getPos());

        float radius_i = ...; // radius of ball `i`
        float radius_j = ...; // radius of ball `j`

        if (d <= radius_i + radius_j)
        {
            // ball `i` and `j` are colliding
            // [...]
        }
    }
}
```